# How to access in Laravel an array or object directly?

Tags: laravel, session

I have an array like this:

```
$aMyArray = ['name' => 'test', 'description' => 'my description'];
session(['aMyArray' => $aMyArray]);
```

If I want to change a value in array, I must retrieve first the whole array modify it and set it again.

```
$aMyArray = session('aMyArray');
$aMyArray['name'] = 'test2';
session(['aMyArray' => $aMyArray]);
```

but, I want to access/modify the array directly.

in Zend Framework 3 I can do this:

```
$sessionContainer->aMyArray['name'] = 'test2';
```

that's it. It directly changes the value in the array.

Is there a solution for laravel?

Answer (score 0):

import session :

```
use Session;
```

to set value :

```
Session::put('variableName', $value);
```

to get value :

```
Session::get('variableName');
```

Comment: this is in my question too. this is not the solutions I want. It is not directly access.